# Jquery sliding ul li

Tags: jquery, list, menu, slide

I'm trying to make a simple navigation menu with jquery, where you hover over one of the li, and a sub ul li slides in under it. I can get it to work with slideToggle() just fine, but can't for the life of me get slide to work. (I was debugging with click but need it to be hover).
Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for the page and all the DOM to be fully loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Add the 'hover' event listener to our drop down class
        $(".dropdown").click(function() {
            // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and
            // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
            //$(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
            $(this).find(".sub_navigation").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    min-width:200px;
} 
ul#navigation {
    float:left;
} 
ul#navigation li {
    float:left;
    border:1px black solid;
    min-width:200px;
} 
ul.sub_navigation {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
ul.sub_navigation li {
    clear:both;
    margin-left: 9999px;
    float: left;
} 
a,a:active,a:visited {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

List

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('home.php', 'body');">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('projects.php', 'body');">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub_navigation">
                <!-- pull projects with P H P -->
                <?php
                    require('config/config.php');
                    //pull all data from projects table
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects") or die('Unable to query!');
                    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    //make sure there is at least 1 project 
                    if ($num_results > 0) {
                            //loop to catch each project in database
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            //return in list each project name
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="openproject.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>"><? echo $row['name']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                            }                             
                    } else {
                    //return to add a project
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="createproj.php">Add a project</a></li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pubfiles.php', 'body');">Public Files</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('users.php', 'body');">Users</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('settings.php', 'body');">Settings</a></li>
            <!-- only pull if admin and logged in per P H P session-->
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('admin.php', 'body');">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for `show()` has the wrong signature: http://api.jquery.com/show/

It can be:
`.show()`
or
`.show( duration [, callback] )`
or
`.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`

In your case, you can use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to slide horizontally:

```
$(this).find(".sub_navigation").animate({ width: "toggle" }, 1000);
```

**Edit:**
Althrough if you are using the jQuery UI effects, the syntax is correct. Make sure you have included the jQuery UI .js file in the page and that this file was built with the effects module.

Comment: Are you sure you've included the jQuery UI js built with the effects module in the page? This is exclusive for the jQuery UI effects. I've maded an edit.

Comment: I have jquery.effects.core, effects.slide, ui.core included. I went ahead and took for advise on using animate instead though, and it's working. Just need to redo the list to make it show up as a bar. Any idea on making the populate for ul li side by side instead of up/down?

I'm new to jquery, so would those be the js i need to include if i was to use slide?

Comment: Yes, the build would be right if you want the use the slide effect.

Comment: Ah, because I tried my original adding in those includes and it was still no go. Animate worked just fine though.

Off topic but it will finish up my questions for this. Can you make 2 li's side by side instead of up/down from each other? To be honest I've never understanded the structure of ul li I just know that's how it goes.

Comment: UL and LI elements are list elements and are used for menus because of its semantic meaning (a menu is a "list" of options). Aside from this, it turns out that is easy to style menus with this markup. Answering your new question: you can set the `float: left;` to make the LIs became a horizontal menu.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> .show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
       $(this).find(".sub_navigation").show("slow");  
       //or $(this).find(".sub_navigation").slideDown(); 
   },function() {
       $(this).find(".sub_navigation").hide('slow');    
       // or $(this).find(".sub_navigation").slideUp(); 
});
```

Comment: or this `$(this).find(".sub_navigation").slideToggle()` , might chuck in `is(':visible')` making sure it is visible before hide or something, +1 anyways man. `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks man :). yes, he had used `$(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle();`

Comment: I need it to show up from the left or right. slideToggle does work, but as far as I know is only up or down. trying to make a sub bar under the main navigation bar for the ul li's.